# Gatsby v5 and GraphQL: 'Error: Schema must contain uniquely named types but contains multiple types named "File".'

Tags: node.js, graphql, gatsby, graphql-schema, gatsby-source-graphql

I'm developing my website using Gatsby v5 and I'm currently struggling with a GraphQL issue.

## Problem

I use a static GraphQL query to pull the *openGraphImageUrl* from some GitHub repositories and display each in a card component. In order to have more control over the images, I wrote a resolver that downloads the files behind the *openGraphImageUrl* and adds it them as *File* nodes to the GraphQL data layer so that I can use them with the `<GatsbyImage>` component.

This approach generally works, I can build the website and the static query provides the information from the repository. The resolver correctly adds the `image` node with the downloaded file, which I can use with `<GatsbyImage>` as expected *(see further down)*.

The problem that I'm facing is the following error message, which only occurs when I make changes to a page and then save it (e.g. *index.tsx*) **after** successfully running `gatsby develop`, but it does not occur when modifying individual components that are not pages (e.g. *code.tsx* - see below):

> Missing onError handler for invocation 'building-schema', error was 'Error: Schema must contain uniquely named types but contains multiple types named "File".'

This happens when the `building schema` step runs again (triggered by saving changes to pages), which is where the build process then gets stuck after the error occurs.

I have searched hours on end to figure out the problem and I also consulted ChatGPT, but to no avail. I'm currently still a beginner with regards to Gatsby, React and Typescript.

The error message suggests that the "File" type is redefined, I just don't understand why that happens and what I'm doing wrong. How can I avoid that the "File" type is redefined in the schema? My setup is as follows below.

## Setup

### gatsby-config.ts

This is where I have set up the access to GitHub's GraphQL API:

```js
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
});

import type { GatsbyConfig } from "gatsby";

const config: GatsbyConfig = {
graphqlTypegen: true,
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-graphql",
      options: {
        typeName: "GitHub",
        fieldName: "github",
        url: "https://api.github.com/graphql",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN}`,
        },        
        fetchOptions: {},
      },
    },
    //... skipping the rest
  ],
};

export default config;
```

### gatsby-node.js

The resolver is created as shown below. On a `GitHub_Repository` node, it adds an `image` node of type `File` and downloads the image data from the *openGraphImageUrl* of the repository. It then saves that as a temporary file, reads the blob into a buffer and then creates the actual node from the buffer by calling `createFileNodeFromBuffer()`.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const { createFileNodeFromBuffer } = require("gatsby-source-filesystem");

exports.createResolvers = async ({
  actions: { createNode },
  createNodeId,
  cache,
  store,
  createResolvers,
}) => {
  const resolvers = {
    GitHub_Repository: {
      image: {
        type: "File",
        resolve: async (source) => {
          const imageUrl = source.openGraphImageUrl;
          const imageNodeId = createNodeId(imageUrl);
          const response = await fetch(imageUrl);
          const buffer = await response.buffer();
          const dirPath = path.join(process.cwd(), "public", "tmp");
          if (!fs.existsSync(dirPath)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(dirPath, { recursive: true });
          }
          const filePath = path.join(
            dirPath,
            imageNodeId,
          );
          fs.writeFileSync(filePath, buffer);
          const fileNode = await createFileNodeFromBuffer({
            buffer,
            store,
            cache,
            createNode,
            createNodeId,
            name: imageNodeId,
          });
          return fileNode;
        },
      },
    },
  };
  createResolvers(resolvers);
};
```

### code.tsx

This is what the query looks like:

```js
function QueryGitHubRepositories(): Repository[] {
  const data: Data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    {
      github {
        viewer {
          pinnedItems(first: 6, types: REPOSITORY) {
            nodes {
              ... on GitHub_Repository {
                id
                name
                url
                openGraphImageUrl
                image {
                  childImageSharp {
                    gatsbyImageData(layout: FIXED, width: 336, height: 168)
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  return data.github.viewer.pinnedItems.nodes.map((node) => node);
}
```

## TL;DR

Here is the rest of the related code, for completeness.

### code.tsx *(continued)*

I defined the following types for the query method (also in *code.tsx*):

```js
type Repository = {
  name?: string | null;
  url?: string | null;
  openGraphImageUrl?: string | null;
  image?: {
    childImageSharp: {
      gatsbyImageData?: any | null;
    };
  } | null;
};

type Data = {
  github: {
    viewer: {
      pinnedItems: {
        nodes: Repository[];
      };
    };
  };
};
```

The query data is used here to build the code section with the repository cards (also in *code.tsx*):

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby";
import { GatsbyImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image";

//skipping type definitions and query here, since they're already shown above

const RepositoryCard = ({ repository }: { repository: Repository }) => {
  const imageItem = repository.image?.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData ?? "";
  const altText = repository.name ?? "repository";

  return (
    <div>
      <a href={repository.url ?? ""} target="_blank">
        <div className="flex h-fit flex-col">
          <GatsbyImage image={imageItem} alt={altText} />
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

const CodeSection = () => {
  const repositories: Repository[] = QueryGitHubRepositories();

  return (
    <div className="w-full">        
      <div className="flex flex-col">
        {repositories.map((repository) => (
          <RepositoryCard key={repository.name} repository={repository} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CodeSection;
```

## Update

I also tried different implementations and I had a look at Paul Scanlon's two blog posts about [adding data to Gatsby's GraphQL data layer](https://paulie.dev/posts/2021/07/gatsby-source-nodes/) and [modifying Gatsby's GraphQL data types using createSchemaCustomization](https://paulie.dev/posts/2021/07/gatsby-create-schema-customization/). However, I couldn't get that to work properly, probably because in his blog posts, the nodes are added without any source plugins, while I am using `gatsby-plugin-graphql`.

Suggestions for alternative implementations are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution. I just had to replace `gatsby-source-graphql` with `gatsby-source-github-api`, because the former apparently doesn't support incremental builds:

### gatsby-config.ts

```js
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
});

import type { GatsbyConfig } from "gatsby";

const config: GatsbyConfig = {
graphqlTypegen: true,
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-github-api`,
      options: {
        url: "https://api.github.com/graphql",      
        token: `${process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN}`,
        graphQLQuery: `
          query{
            user(login: "someUserName") {
              pinnedItems(first: 6, types: [REPOSITORY]) {
                edges {
                  node {
                    ... on Repository {
                      name
                      openGraphImageUrl
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }`
      }
    },
    //... skipping the rest
  ],
};

export default config;
```

### gatsby-node.js

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const { createFileNodeFromBuffer } = require("gatsby-source-filesystem");

exports.createResolvers = async ({
  actions: { createNode },
  createNodeId,
  cache,
  store,
  createResolvers,
}) => {
  const resolvers = {
    GithubDataDataUserPinnedItemsEdgesNode: {
      image: {
        type: "File",
        resolve: async (source) => {
          const imageUrl = source.openGraphImageUrl;
          const imageNodeId = createNodeId(imageUrl);
          const response = await fetch(imageUrl);
          const buffer = await response.buffer();
          const dirPath = path.join(process.cwd(), "public", "tmp");
          if (!fs.existsSync(dirPath)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(dirPath, { recursive: true });
          }
          const filePath = path.join(
            dirPath,
            imageNodeId,
          );
          fs.writeFileSync(filePath, buffer);
          const fileNode = await createFileNodeFromBuffer({
            buffer,
            store,
            cache,
            createNode,
            createNodeId,
            name: imageNodeId,
          });
          return fileNode;
        },
      },
    },
  };
  createResolvers(resolvers);
};
```

### code.tsx

#### Type definitions

```js
type Repository = {
  openGraphImageUrl?: string | null;
  image?: {
    childImageSharp?: {
      gatsbyImageData?: any | null;
    } | null;
  } | null;
};

type Data = {
  githubData: {
    data: {
      user: {
        pinnedItems: {
          edges: {
            node: Repository;
          }[];
        };
      };
    };
  };
};
```

#### Query

```js
function QueryGitHubRepositories(): Repository[] {
  const data: Data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    {
      githubData {
        data {
          user {
            pinnedItems {
              edges {
                node {
                  openGraphImageUrl
                  image {
                    childImageSharp {
                      gatsbyImageData
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  const repos = data.githubData.data.user.pinnedItems.edges.map(
    (edge) => edge.node
  );

  return repos;
}
```